# Make div with curve?

Tags: html, css

This seems like a vague question but you will see exactly what i want after you read this, i have the design that i should "convert" to a static HTML page, but i am not figuring out how i will should do this.

The design:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtkeZ.jpg

The curve im talking about is the one where the logo is and the other one at the bottom.

What i have so far (a bit messy):

```css
body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ul, ol, li, dl, dt, dd, img, form, fieldset, input, blockquote {
 margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
}

body {
 font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; line-height: 24px;
 background: #eee url(images/body-bg.jpg) center top no-repeat;
}

#container {
 width: 80%; margin: 0 auto; height:1000px; margin-top: -75px; background-color: blue;
}

#destaques {
 width:100%;
 height: 40%;
 background-color: grey;
}

#header {
    overflow: hidden;
 padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}

#mllcont {
 height:200px;
 background-color: grey;
}

#slidecont {
 height: 650px;
 background-color: red;
}

#squares {
   width:100%;
   height:250px;
}

#divs div { 
        height: 250px; 
        width: 20%; 
        border: 0px solid red; 
        margin-left: 2.5%; 
        margin-right: 2.5%; 
        float: left; /*Here you can also use display: inline-block instead of float:left*/
        background: orange; 
}

 #header h1 {
  float: left;
 }


#content, #footer, #header  {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Particle</title>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>

<body>

 <div id="slidecont">

  <div id="mllcont">

   <div id="logo">
   </div>

   <div id="header">
     <ul id="categories">
      <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu4</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>

   <div id="languages">
   </div>

  </div>
  </div>

 <div id="container">

   <div id="squares">
       <div id="divs">
          <div>One</div>
          <div>Two</div>
          <div>Three</div>
          <div>Four</div>
       </div>
   </div> 

   <div id="destaques">

   </div>
   
   <div id="Projetos">

   </div>

 </div> 

  <div id="footer">
   <ul id="credits">
    <li><a href="http://wordpress.org" class="wordpress">Powered by WordPress</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.blog.spoongraphics.co.uk" class="spoongraphics">Theme by SpoonGraphics</a></li>
   </ul>
   <p id="back-top"><a href="#header">Back to top</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You probably want to use a background image for that. Not CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use transparent background images (.png or .gif) and assign them to a position in each div, and also use absolutely positioned divs with a z-index heirarchy to achieve the visual effect that you're after, though if the site needs to be layout-reponsive, you've got a lot of work cut out for you using this method.

For example, extract the top curve (the white bit and the blue bit) in your image editor of choice, making sure to leave the background transparent and save it correctly. Then it's just a case of using code along the lines of:

```
//STYLES CSS
.splash{
   background-image:url("icewater.jpg");
   width:1289px;
   height:513px;
   position:relative;
   z-index:1;
}
.top-curved-section{
   position:relative;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   z-index:2;
   background-image:url("blue-white-curve.gif");
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-position:top left;
//Padding to get your logo element to display properly
   padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
//These heights are guesses to force the size of the div for background image
   width:400px;
   height:150px;
}
```

HTML, in its most simplistic form:

```
    <div class="splash">
<div class="top-curved-section">
<img src="yourlogo.png" alt="Your Logo">
</div>
</div>
```

Hopefully this helps and sets you on your way. This code in untested. You can apply the same principal for the bottom curved section of your splash page by using:

```
.bottom-curved-section{
       position:relative;
       bottom:0;
       right:0;
       text-align:right;
       z-index:2;
       background-image:url("blue-white-curve2.gif");
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:bottom right;
    //Padding to get your logo element to display properly
       padding: 0 20px 20px 0;
    //These heights are guesses to force the size of the div for background image
       width:400px;
       height:150px;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete awsner, im going to take the images and try to do that.